# How to get my Windows 10 Universal App to recognize my Microsoft Band

Tags: usb, windows-10, microsoft-band

I'm trying to make a Windows 10 Universal App to make a third party tile for my Microsoft Band but it doesn't say in the documentation how to get my App to recognize the Band through USB. It only says how to do it through Bluetooth. The documentation also doesn't tell me how to access the GPS sensor. How do I do all these things?

Comment: I'm not familiar with developing for the band, but I thought this session from BUILD might be helpful for you if you haven't checked it out yet. http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2015/2-619

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first question, USB for the Band is used for charging. In order for you to test, you need to go through via Bluetooth. Your setup should be

Visual Studio > Launch App on your Device (mobile is connected to your laption via USB) > Test App on Mobile (which talks to Band via Bluetooth).

Note: Make sure Band is paired with the Mobile you are using to test.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your second question, you can not subscribe to GPS on the band. It is not opened for thrid party app access. GPS is exclusive at this point.